# Ubuntu installation on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, system-installation

I am starting a project under Linux and have difficulty with installation on Virtual Box. I have no idea why during the installation, the following screen shows.

VirtualBox: 5.1.6 version 
Ubuntu : 16.04.1 Desktop i386

[image]

Comment: Press the key combination `ctrl-alt-f1` and then `ctrl-alt-f7` and see what happens. If that doesn't work, try `right ctrl + f1` and then `right ctrl + f7`

Comment: Try disabling any 2D/3D options for the graphics card for the VM in virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Try these options:

1. Install Ubuntu on a different host OS.
2. Wait a bit (when I see that garbage, it disappears in 10 seconds.)
3. Try to install a different guest OS, or a different version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Additionally, this question should be moved to AskUbuntu, as it discusses a problem on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, then <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> +
<kbd>F7</kbd>.

This will reset the graphics adapter, first into text mode (TTY1), then into
graphical mode again (TTY7).

http://askubuntu.com/questions/815960/-/815966